# Angular material 2 does it support translation

Tags: angular, angular-material2, ngx-translate

Am trying out *Angular-material* for the first time and when I tested the mat-select with *ngx-translate* it did not update the language, not until re-clicking on the input will change take effect.

So does the framework support localization/translation or am I using it wrong

code:

```
 <mat-form-field>
   <mat-select placeholder="City" [formControl]="city">
      <mat-option *ngFor="let city of cityList" [value]="city.id">
        {{city.name | translate}}
      </mat-option>
  </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
```

Comment: any error you get , i have not used ngx translate but i dnt think it is down to material not supporting it

Comment: no errors the code works even with normal html its material that is not updating the text when language is switched, I even tried to switch text by using a custom pipe and an object with no ngx-translate, but material just would not update the view not until I click on the input. I think their components don't support async/dynamic input I don't know

Answer (score 0):

Isn't that because of how Angular handles template expressions?

Angular executes expressions after every change detection cycle. Change detection cycles are triggered by many asynchronous activities such as promise resolutions, http results, timer, keypresses and mouse moves events.

that's why a click triggers the expression where the translate Pipe is executed

Comment: How would you fix this issue (Try switching the language and notice the infamous ChangeDetection error in the console)  - https://stackblitz.com/edit/ng-material-mat-select-translate-issue The temporary workaround I have is to use the native select with material directive which seems to work just fine.

Comment: @JagpreetSingh from the link you posted , i'm unable to repro the issue you are stating , can you explain it so that i can help you out

Comment: @webruster Actually, I fixed the link on line 25 `this.cd.detectChanges()`

Comment: @JagpreetSingh so what is ur question now? , i mean i can see that issue is fixed , so anything else u want?